# Eclipse 3.4 Vs Eclipse 3.6

Tags: java, eclipse

Which one is better and in what way because I do use FindBugs, PMD reports and CheckStyles plugins along with code coverage plugin. If anyone could guide me please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

The latest version is almost always the better one. But you can try yourself. You can have as many different eclipse versions installed as you like. So grab a 3.6, add your plugins and enjoy the advantages.

Your plugins should run in 3.6 and if you encounter problems, I'm pretty sure there are updated versions available already.

- [Eclipse 3.5 - New and Noteworthy](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-all.html)
- [Eclipse 3.6 - New and Noteworthy](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news.html)

Comment: +1 for the links and for hint that both versions can run in parallel

Comment: @Nils - I usually have 4-5 different versions or versions with different sets of plugins up and running (like one for plugin development, another for android, ...)

Comment: Same over here, it would never occur to me to mix my C environment with my Jave one and even for the languages I have several eclipses...

Comment: Updated link for [Eclipse 3.6 New and Noteworthy](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news.html) (didn't check 3.5 link)

Answer (score 1):

3.6 is better because the number is looking nicer

Answer (score 1):

If you already use Eclipse 3.4 and have a functional working environment and is pleased with it, then stay with that since a lot of small things change from release to release.

There is a lot of new facilities which may be interesting to you, but not necessarily anything warranting an upgrade.  You can have a 3.6 installation next to a 3.4 installation without any problems so you can try it out, while being productive in 3.4.